# JQuery Flip cancel feature

Tags: jquery, flip

I'm using the Flip plugin with Jquery and I need to make sure that certain element loses the inversion functionality. I've tried the following possibilities but not success:

```
$("#element").off();

$("#element").off(".flip");
```

Plugin: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: A very quick google of "jquery flip plugin" provides a page with 100+ (I didn't count them) "flip plugins" - could you be a bit more specific which plugin are you having difficulty with?

Comment: This plugin has no such functionality. Have you considered not applying the plugin to said elements in the first place?

Comment: could try deleting the flip object thats been applied to the object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a question of better understanding of the plugin for me, I did the following:

```
$("#element").flip({ trigger: "manual" });
```

In this way all flip actions should be called manually (no longer by mouse action) by following the necessary logic code, using the following actions:

```
$("#element").flip(false); // Back

$("#element").flip(true); // Front

$("#element").flip("toogle"); // Inversion
```

Att;